# How to count maximum number of product in specific category with specific seller through sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

#### Table prd

```
seller_id   seller_name   category_id   category_name   product_sku  product_sku
11          abc           10001         Fashion         sku1         20001
11          abc           10001         Fashion         sku2         20002
11          abc           10002         Home and Living sku3         20003
12          bcd           10001         Fashion         skua         20004
13          cde           10002         Home and Living sku1         20005
```

#### Expected Result

```
seller_id   seller_name   category_name   no_of_product
11          abc           Fashion         2
12          bcd           Fashion         1
13          cde           Home and Living 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select seller_id, seller_name, category_name, cnt
from (select seller_id, seller_name, category_name, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by seller_id, seller_name order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by seller_id, seller_name, category_name
     ) ssc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that in the event of ties, this returns an arbitrary highest value.  If you want all of them, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.